# Create vim map that executes tab (autocomplete)

Tags: vim, autocomplete

## Background:

I have a vim mapping that helps me easily get to other directories in my code base.

```
cmap j1 `current_base`/path/to/section1/
cmap j2 `current_base`/other/path/
```

`current_base` is a bash script that returns a path relative to the current file. (for example if I'm in `/foo/bar/code/some/path` it would return `/foo/bar/code`.

Now, in vim I can type `:e j1` to get

```
:e `current_base`/path/to/section1/
```

If I then press the `tab` key once, it will execute `current_base` and replace what I have with

```
:e /foo/bar/code/path/to/section1/
```

If I then press the `tab` key again I get a list of all files and directories in that folder, because I have `set wildmode=list:longest` in my vimrc.

I want the vim mapping to autocomplete for me, so I don't have to hit tab twice every time, but this:

```
cmap j1 `current_base`/path/to/section1/<tab><tab>
```

results in:

```
`current_base`/path/to/section1/^I^I
```

## Question:

How can I get a vim mapping to actually autocomplete, as if I pressed the `tab` key, instead of inserting `^I`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `'wildcharm'` option:

```
set wildcharm=<C-z>
```

which you can use where you would use `<Tab>` if it worked in a command-line mapping:

```
cmap j1 `current_base`/path/to/section1/<C-z><C-z>
```

Comment: Perfect! I actually ended up using `<tab>` as a `wildcharm` just to make it easy to remember later

Comment: Wow, I never thought about using `<Tab>`, here.